# Custom ListView in Winforms?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, listview, gdi+

Is it possible to draw some strings onto a listview?

I overridden the OnPaint event but I don't see any change. I checked out some code on custom listview, but it seems like people are using p/invoke, etc. Why?

Isn't list as customizable as other winforms, like the Button control?

I am not gonna customize wildly, just paint some more after it's done the standard painting.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
 class MyCustomlistView : ListView
    {
        public MyCustomlistView()
            : base()
        {
            SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint, true);
        }
        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnPaint(e);
            e.Graphics.DrawString("This is a custom string", new Font(FontFamily.GenericSerif, 10, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Black, new PointF(0, 50));
        }

    }
```

Comment: This does not work with a ListView. It simply makes the ListView draw nothing.

Answer (score 10):

You can't just override the `OnPaint()` method. That method doesn't do anything in a ListView. Similarly, `OwnerDrawn` lets you custom draw each cell, but doesn't let you paint over the control as a whole.

Use an [ObjectListView](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/list/objectlistview.aspx) (an open source wrapper around .NET WinForms ListView) and use its [Overlay feature](http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/recipes.html#how-can-i-put-an-image-or-some-text-over-the-top-of-the-listview). That lets you effortlessly do something like this:

[image: text over a ListView]

This was produced by this code:

```
this.olv1.OverlayText.Alignment = ContentAlignment.BottomRight;
this.olv1.OverlayText.Text = "Trial version";
this.olv1.OverlayText.BackColor = Color.White;
this.olv1.OverlayText.BorderWidth = 2.0f;
this.olv1.OverlayText.BorderColor = Color.RoyalBlue;
this.olv1.OverlayText.TextColor = Color.DarkBlue;
```

Answer (score 1):

Set the [OwnerDraw](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.ownerdraw.aspx) property to true.

You can then handle the [DrawItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.drawitem.aspx), [DrawSubItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.drawsubitem.aspx), and [DrawColumnHeader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.drawcolumnheader.aspx) events to draw on specific elements of the ListView.