# How to change the ListView column header's font for each column in vb.net 2005?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio, listview, visual-studio-2005

I have a listview and i want to make one column's font smaller than the other column to fit form design. How will i do that?

Comment: Is this winforms or wpf?  Add a tag to the question

Comment: @Richard Banks I think there is no WPF at VS 2005.

Comment: @VMAtm There's extensions you could get for VS2005 to do WPF and WCF work.  It's only available via CNet these days (http://cnet.co/pdy9hW)

Comment: @Richard Banks Still think that the OP meant the classic winforms.

Answer (score 0):

Doing this in WinForms is going to be difficult to say the least if you try it yourself.  I'd recommend looking at something like [ObjectListView](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/list/objectlistview.aspx) and see if it meets your needs.

P.S. The ObjectListView info came from an answer to the "[Custom ListView in Winforms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1604704/custom-listview-in-winforms)" question.