# ListView with images only with WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I'm trying to do something very simple with c# and winforms, something i could easily do with WPF, but winforms seems so messy i'm pulling my hair off trying to make it (and yes, i have to use winforms).

Basically i have a button, when i click on it, i want to display an horizontal listview (or something else, but it has to be horizontal and allows me to bind a collection on it) which has 64*64px images as items, on a black 50% transparent background, and i want to handle click event on every image.

This has to be super-easy, but i can't find anything on the internet explaining more or less what i'm trying to achieve.

Can someone please help me ?

Comment: In which part you have problem?

Comment: @RezaAghaei every one ! binding, displaying images only, transparent background, stretching list size to elements inside... i really HATE winforms ahah

Comment: Create a custom control and draw items using GDI+ or host your wpf control in your windows form.

Comment: [Walkthrough: Hosting a WPF Composite Control in Windows Forms](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742215(v=vs.100).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

This has been answered before: 
[Custom ListView in Winforms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1604704/custom-listview-in-winforms)

basically, you can implement a class that allows you to access the graphics device on that listview, from there, you can draw images, lines and other stuff.

Enjoy :)

Comment: doesn't answer my question, overriding the onPaint method doesn't allow me to draw bound images from my collection..

Comment: It should. Since you now have the graphics context, you can do whatever you want with it, including drawing images. The "e.Graphics" object is basically what you're targetting. But I agree that it is FAR from the ease of WPF :)

Comment: tell me about it ahah